# Scala Typeclass for composites

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-cats

I have a sum type, Mapping:

```
sealed trait Mapping
final case class XMapping(a:String)
final case class FallbackMapping(mappings: List[Mapping])
```

I have a typeclass defined as follows:

```
final case class Param(x:String)

trait ParameterLoader[T] {
  def load(mapping:T) : List[Param]
}
```

With some instances:

```
object DefaultParameterLoaders {
  implicit val  xParameterLoader= new QueryParameterLoader[XMapping] {
    override def load(mapping: XMapping): List[Param] = List(Param(mapping.a))
  }

  implicit val fallbackParameterLoader = new ParameterLoader[FallbackMapping] {

    override def load(mapping: FallbackMapping): List[Param] =
      mapping.mappings.flatMap(x => ???)

  }
}
```

I can't find a way to have the implicit instances passed to the flatMap above. The error I get is that I'm missing an instance of ParameterLoader[Mapping]. Is there some way of telling the compiler that it should use whatever typeclass instances are in scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type system is looking for a `ParameterLoader[Mapping]` specifically, meaning that a `ParameterLoader[XMapping]`/`ParameterLoader[FallbackMapping]` is not specific enough.  You need to provide a `ParameterLoader[Mapping]`.  You can do this using your existing definitions.

```
implicit def mappingLoader(implicit xpLoader: ParameterLoader[XMapping], fmLoader: ParameterLoader[FallbackMapping]) = new ParameterLoader[Mapping] { 
  def load(mapping: Mapping): List[QueryParam] = 
    mapping match {
      case xm: XMapping = xpLoader.load(xm)
      case fm: FallbackMapping => fmLoader.load(fm)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, have your flatmap perform the matching logic:

```
implicit def fallbackParameterLoader(implicit xpLoader: ParameterLoader[XMapping]) = new ParameterLoader[FallbackMapping] {
  override def load(mapping: FallbackMapping): List[Param] =
    mapping.mappings.flatMap { 
      case xm: XMapping = xpLoader.load(xm)
      case fm: FallbackMapping => this.load(fm)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I was hoping of somehow automating this. This locks in the instances used, whereas ideally I'd like to use whatever instances the client has in scope. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes.  Instead of specifying the parameter loader explicitly as I have done, use `implicitly[ParameterLoader[XMapping]].load(xm)` in place of `xParameterLoader.load(xm)`.  However, this will use the parameter loader that's in scope at the time of construction for your parameter loader.

Comment: I've updated my answer to support your use case.  This will derive a mappingLoader based on whatever parameter loaders that you have in scope.  Keep in mind that having derivations like this, behavior can be confusing simply because imports can change behavior.  Make sure this is well documented and make your team aware of how it works.

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any other questions.